# My TextView array prints only the first element in the TextView array and not all elements

Tags: java, android, textview

My TextView array prints only the first element in the TextView array and not all elements, new to android. Please help me out.

Guys there was a typo, I had forgotten to show the increment of i in the code below. I have actually used increment of i, but yet only the first textview appears. Please check it out now and help me.

```
    Iterator<String> i1 = processesOccupyingHugeMemory.iterator();

    TextView[] text = new TextView[processesOccupyingHugeMemory.size()];
    int i=0;
    while(i1.hasNext())
    {
        text[i] = new TextView(this);
        text[i].setText(i1.next());
        text[i].setAllCaps(true);
        text[i].setId(i);
        text[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        myLinearLayout.addView(text[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

}

XML Code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: where do you increment `i`?

Comment: Can you show code for `params`? If that is `MATCH_PARENT` in width, change it to `WRAP_CONTENT`. **OR** if you need the textview in different lines, change linear layout orientation to `VERTICAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot incrementing `i` in `while` loop.

```
    Iterator<String> i1 = processesOccupyingHugeMemory.iterator();

    TextView[] text = new TextView[processesOccupyingHugeMemory.size()];
    int i=0;
    while(i1.hasNext())
    {
        text[i] = new TextView(this);
        text[i].setText(i1.next());
        text[i].setAllCaps(true);
        text[i].setId(i);
        text[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        myLinearLayout.addView(text[i]);
        i++;
    }
```

Other than that:

Make sure you have used width `WRAP_CONTENT` in `params`, you use for textview.

And if you want each textview in new line, then you will need to set orientation `vertical` for linear layout in xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess it was a typo error, I had not copied that part. I am incrementing i!

Comment: @Pavanraotk Can you show code for params? If that is MATCH_PARENT in width, change it to WRAP_CONTENT. OR if you need the textview in different lines, change linear layout orientation to VERTICAL.

Comment: it wokred :)... Keeping it as VERTICAL did it, but not sure how(since I am new to Android).

Comment: @Pavanraotk see [document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:orientation). That will explain clearly :) Basically, horizontal means put the views in one line, and whole line was being occupied by first textview only (as its size was match_parent). Got difference now?

Comment: Thanks Dhruti, makes sense now :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You have to increment `i` , you are always use 0 for the variable `i`

Comment: I am incrementing i, I forgot to put that in the code

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the same id to the textview each time. Increment the id value in the loop.

Comment: I did not know how to edit my question in stackoverflow, realized it was too easy. As soon as I put the question, I realized i have missed my i++, it is already done :(